# Can we run query in Laravel migration?

Tags: php, laravel

Can we run Eloquent of DB queries in Laravel migrations?

I mean I want to create the columns in the new table by getting the result set from another table.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible or not, I would strongly advise against it. Keep migrations for database building, and leave database seeding to things like seeders.

Comment: I agree with Brian.  To me, a "migration" ought to be a process which reliably transforms a database from one topology to another.  This is probably not the right place to do other things, such as seeding them with data.  Instead, I would say: "first run the migration, then run this script."  The migration steps alters the schema but does nothing else.

Comment: I agree with Brian.  To me, a "migration" ought to be a process which reliably transforms a database from one topology to another.  This is probably not the right place to do other things, such as seeding them with data.  Instead, I would say: "first run the migration, then run this script."

Comment: You can, as has already been answered, try to avoid using model instances and keep the migrations very close to the database, you don't want changes to your model (codebase) to break your migration (database) further down the line

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run queries in your migration. I've never tried Eloquent, but using `DB::statement` is great for preloading a few rows or updating existing. Just make sure it's done outside of the Schema block.

```
public function up() {
      Schema::table('my_table', function(Blueprint $table) {
      // stuff goes here
      });
      DB::statement('UPDATE my_table SET column = 1');
      DB::table('my_table')->insert(['column' => 1, 'other_column' => 2]);
      DB::statement("INSERT INTO my_table SELECT * FROM other_table");
}
```

Comment: Is updating/inserting data using migrations advisable?

Comment: If it's a one-off, and for loading existing data into a new column, then it would be best in either a migration or a seeder. In a migration, you can be sure that the data is loaded.